# Is there a way to use surefire-plugin report with junit and cucumber?

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm using Junit 4 to run Cucumber scenarios and surefire plugin to generate summary report, but my problem is that in the report each step from my scenarios reported as separate testcase, as a result 1 scenario with 9 step is reported as 9 separate tests. Is there a way to configure surefire to print the accurate info? Thank you.

[Surefire report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkf7R.png)

[Cucumber summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcY1W.png)

Comment: Upgrade cucumber. https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:%22io.cucumber%22%20AND%20a:%22cucumber-java%22

Comment: Thank you very much! The solution was on the surface, but I couldn't see it